# Ubuntu 21.04 kernel 5.13.12 - Battery drainage during Suspend mode at 1% per hour aprox

Tags: power-management, battery, 21.04, xps

I put my XPS 15 9510 OLED in suspend mode at night, let us say at 60% battery charge, the next day after 8 hours in suspend mode it will be at 51% battery charge, meaning a discharge rate of 1%/hour aprox., is that normal? In theory, it is only powering the memory, I have 64GB, I am using Ubuntu 21.04 with Kernel 5.13.12, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks pretty normal to me. My older laptop has a hard time sleeping with Windows, even if it starts with an almost full battery. I cannot test this with ubuntu though, but logic tells me the story would be similar.